# Should add feature to see Profile Visit dates and more

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, views

I think it would really be cool and helpful if Stack Overflow added a feature that allowed users to also see when the their profiles were visited and by whom. I think this would help with providing users with much more clarity. After all, knowledge is power.

Comment: And how would this feature help in making the content that is posted any better? What would that clarity achieve? What is causing issues now that we lack this clarity?

Comment: To know who is visiting/stalking/monitoring you so that you can filter what you post and/or put on your profile...

Comment: Here where the reputation system brings so many emotions ("Why u downvoted?"), I don't think this clarity will be cool nor helpful...

Comment: I down-voted because it is tagged feature request and I don't see any benefit in having this feature as it fails to explain how it will aid in improving the body of knowledge that SO wants to be. I don't think social media features are needed on a Q/A site. As such my down vote signals to the SE dev team: don't implement this feature.

Comment: @brasofilo I on the other hand, think that it will help me to prevent being downvoted in the future. If they tell me why flaws right now then I can learn from them

Comment: oh okay @rene I understand.

Comment: You're not really presenting a solid argument why this feature is useful... you want knowledge and power, ok, but what will it be user for?

Comment: @brasofilo If you know that your mom or dad or friend have visited your profile, then that can affect how you use this website and what you use it for...

Comment: If you're personally interested in when your profile is viewed you could track the [view_count](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/10488923?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UDo6l2ikDi7R_27) every 15 minutes and build up a dataset your self. By whom is not something you can obtain.

Comment: Aside from the hilarity of driving Jon Skeet insane with notifications (he has 1,714,224 profile views at the time of writing) I fail to see how being able to see who downvoted you would help to "prevent being downvoted in the future". Are you trying to suggest that most people who downvote you are also viewing your profile? I almost never look at the profile of those I downvote. Even if that were the case, what would you do with that information? Ask them to tell you why they downvoted? If they had wanted to do that, they would do so without further harassment.

Comment: @EthanField and how would you even ask them? SE has no messaging system. You'd have to either hope they have an email listed in their profile (and risk annoying them by sending an email) or post an unrelated comment on one of their questions or answers.

Comment: @EthanField I think I get what you're saying, or at least this is my own interpretation of your comment. Seeing who downvoted you would create some kind of circle/loop of communication between the downvoter and the downvotee, since the downvotee "initiated" the communication by asking a question, and then the downvoter "responded" to the communication by downvoting. StacOverFlow is **not** a social network.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul In a sense. The main thing to take away is that (as far as I am aware) there is no provable evidence (I haven't seen any data on it, and I believe only a mod or employee would be able to provide it) to say that downvoters visit the profiles of the downvotee. Even if there were a correlation here (which there may be, we have no data either way) having this knowledge wouldn't help you. Even if you could contact them somehow, they are not obliged to explain their voting choices to you.

Comment: @TheWanderer < You can do this. It's possible to notify anyone by @'ing them in a comment. If you knew who viewed your profile, you could open dialogue with them this way, not that I recommend doing so. I am, in fact, against this idea. EDIT: [Apparently I'm wrong.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131372/mentioning-someone-in-a-comment-to-attract-his-her-attention-to-the-question)

Comment: Okay @EthanField I get you.

Answer (score 19):

#### Privacy

This is not a good idea. Online privacy is something that is valued and protected. It's a basic right that internet providers are required to protect and so is any site that gathers personal identifying information (PII) about its users. The total number of profile views and question views can be seen, as are votes. It is all anonymised. Moderators have restrictions on what they can see, and it is logged whenever they access a user's PII. I'm not sure what the employees can see.

#### Overhead

I can imagine providing logs to users who has visited their profile would require a great deal of overhead for popular users. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=profile) has 1,714,155 profile views at the time I'm writing this. Providing that data would be untenable.

Comment: **And database bloating**. Just to add on to what you're saying. I think you're making a good point.

Comment: crazy how that number for Jon went up by 41 in the 57 minutes your answer has been there

Comment: So you'd say that StackOverFlow unlike Google and Facebook aren't selling our data?

Comment: @Patrice now do you see my point?

Comment: @marvinIsSacul no, I see **exactly** the opposite of your point. How useful will it be to someone like Jon to receive daily updates with > 1000 new log entries?  And how would he use any of that data, even if it was less? I seriously don't see why it changes anything who checks your profile.

Comment: @Patrice so StackOverFlow is not a social network - thats why you're saying?

Comment: @marvin Did I say that? Where did I say that? I said I don't see any value in showing you who looked at your profile. In what way would it improve the site? I can't see any benefit.  (and also, I am saying that for some of our top users, the sheer amount of views they get won't provide them anything meaningful)

Comment: Ok okay @Patrice I get you.

Comment: SO isn't a social network and I'm glad that it isn't. People are here to help with programming questions not to chat about the latest cat video or whatever the hot topic of the day is.